# Postman Script executes flawlessly in Postman, failed in Newman

Tags: javascript, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have a script in postman where it executed flawlessly but when I try to run in in Newman, I get a json error in test-script. The script is:

```
const state = pm.environment.get("switch");

    if (state == "serbian" && state != "undefined" && state !== null ) {

pm.test("Question is correct", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().question).to.include("U cilju osiguranja 
sigurnosti i zaštite podataka, molim Vas da odgovorite na par pitanja. Koje 
je ime grada koji odgovara adresi vašeg prebivališta?");
});

} else if (state == "english" && state != "undefined" && state !== null) {
pm.test("Question is correct", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().question).to.include("OK. Let's start with 
few quick questions.||What's the name of the city you live in?");
});
}
```

And the whole test looks like this (which should not impact the issue)

```
// Parse in the response body to check the response
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

// Run the common tests, I know eval is evil
eval(globals.commonTests)();

// Suplement the basic data for variables
var positiveAnswers = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("positiveAnswers"));

// Check if there are still responses to loop through
if ( positiveAnswers.length > 0 && positiveAnswers != "undefined" && 
positiveAnswers !== null ) {

let positiveAnswers = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("positiveAnswers"));
        pm.environment.set("positiveAnswer", positiveAnswers.shift());
        pm.environment.set("positiveAnswers", 
JSON.stringify(positiveAnswers));

// Check the status of a request
pm.test("Next step is as expected", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().locationOrder).to.be.equal("A01");
});   
    postman.setNextRequest("Get question D01 Positive");
    console.log ("Answer sent is: " + pm.environment.get("positiveAnswer"));
}
setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Timeout!');
    },100);
// Do the validation of the response
const state = pm.environment.get("switch");

    if (state == "serbian" && state != "undefined" && state !== null ) {
pm.test("Question is correct", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().question).to.include("U cilju osiguranja 
sigurnosti i zaštite podataka, molim Vas da odgovorite na par pitanja. Koje 
je ime grada koji odgovara adresi vašeg prebivališta?");
});
} else if (state == "english" && state != "undefined" && state !== null) {
pm.test("Question is correct", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().question).to.include("OK. Let's start with 
few quick questions.||What's the name of the city you live in?");
});
}
```

After some debugging, I've found out that the

```
const state = pm.environment.get("switch");
```

returns null in Newman.

The idea is that it checks for the value, then validates the string returned for different languages. So I can't hardcode it, but rather keep it in env, and changing it with another script.
Tried to do

```
var state = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("switch"));
```

where I made had put the variable in quotes, same result. Does anyone know how can I fix the issue?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYiR.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71v5E.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPEDL.png

Comment: Where is `switch` defined? (from pm.environment.get("switch") ?

Comment: Inside the environment variable

Comment: And how are you setting the env file when running the script in newman?

Comment: I run my code with npm run <name> which in turn runs this script        
    `async.series([
 function(next) {
  newman.run({
   collection: require('../rules.json'),
   globals: require('../alch_env_dev.json'),
   reporters: 'cli',
   bail: false
  }, next);
}]) `

Comment: Could you post the contents of `alch_env_dev.json`?

Comment: Absolutely. You can find it here https://api.myjson.com/bins/n8hd6 Use http://jsonprettyprint.com (or whatever you prefer) to make it more readable